# EPPlus: ListDataValidation slows Package.Save

Tags: c#, epplus, epplus-4

I use EPPlus to generate a spreadsheet with a lot of dropdowns.
The dropdowns are generated using the following code:

```
private void SetDropDown(string destColumn, int row, string selectedValue, 
IEnumerable<string> options) 
{
    int colNum = GetColumnNumByLetter(destColumn);
    var dropDown = _sheet.Cells[row,colNum].DataValidation.AddListDataValidation();
    dropDown.ShowErrorMessage = false;
    options.ForEach(x=>dropDown.Formula.Values.Add(x));
    _sheet.Cells[row, colNum].Value = selectedValue;
}
```

We noticed a severe performance issues during testing - call to `ExcelPackage.Save()` took more than 3 seconds for a 50-row sheet and more than 10 seconds for a 100-row sheet. I started to investigate the source code and noticed that EPPlus executes data validation on `Save()` call. When I removed the call to `AddListDataValidation` and 2 subsequent lines I got a huge performance improvement: 100 rows took less than 0.09 seconds.
So, the questions are:
Is there a way to create a dropdown without ExcelDataValidationList? 
Is there a way to create a custom validator and override the validation logic (don't do any validation for lists at all) to speed up spreadsheet saving?
Is there a way to disable spreadsheet validation on Save at all?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out, yes there is.  I struggled to understand how a `ExcelDataValidationCustom` could be used to do various data validations, then looked into subclassing and overriding `Validate()`.  To no avail.

On my way through the code I stumbled upon `ExcelDataValidationCollection.InternalValidationEnabled`.  It appears to be all-or-nothing for the sheet, though.

```
ExcelPackage pkg = ...;
ExcelWorksheet ws = pkg.Worksheets.Add("sheet");
ws.DataValidations.InternalValidationEnabled = false;
```

My (wide) ~2000 row sheets were taking almost 15 minutes, now <10 seconds.